# How to adjust size of BottomSheet with Edittext and button below it?

Tags: android, button, android-edittext, dialog, bottom-sheet

I want to build a BottomSheet to display a view with button and edit text. If I click on the Edittext the Keyboard shows up but it hides the button which is below the edit text.
These pics should show my problems

1)BottomSheet in normal view-First Image

2)BottomSheet hides the button- Second Image

Here is my code for creating BottomSheet

```
addNewListBottomSheet = new BottomSheetDialog(this, R.style.BottomSheetDialogTheme);
        View bottomSheetRootView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.addnewlist_bottomsheet_layout, null);
        addNewListBottomSheet.setContentView(bottomSheetRootView);
```

I also added a specific style

```
<style name="BottomSheet" parent="@style/Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/bottomsheet_round_bg</item>
</style>

<style name="BaseBottomSheetDialog" parent="@style/Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/BottomSheet</item>
</style>

<style name="BottomSheetDialogTheme" parent="BaseBottomSheetDialog">
```

i also tried to change the behavior with

```
addNewListBottomSheet.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

but it doesn't work. Would appreciate an answer.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Put all the content of the bottomsheet in the scrollview and try.

```
<ScrollView layout_behavior = "@string/bottom_sheet....">
<your layout/>
<ScrollView>
```

Comment: If it still don't work, you should try wrapping whole content inside a scrollview.  Scrollview works great in such cases.

Comment: i already did this. But i won't work. Any other idea. Maybe you could post an example for me

Comment: Btw what do you mean with "layout_behavior ="@string/bottom_sheet" in your first answer?

Comment: The problem why your dialog not responding to ui changes may have occurred due to dialog. You can try using "Persistent Bottomsheet" instead of BottomsheetDialog

Comment: okay, but isn't there any solution to my problem. You said something about the layout behavior in your first answer. But what string should I use there?

Comment: Yes, the layout_behavior tag is used in case of persistent bottomsheets, in such cases your bottomsheet is the part of your parent layout, but assigned with the spacial tag "layout_behavior". By setting this tag, you declare a layout as bottomsheet. Later you can control its state by using BottomsheetBehavior in code. As it is part of your parent layout, it responds to UI changes efficiently than dialogs. Also, note that whole of your layout content should be wrapped inside CoordinaterLayout